# What the energy impact depends on? How can I improve that? (Xcode 8, Swift 3, SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit, xcode8

[image]

I am creating a SpriteKit game with Swift3, and my Xcode8 debug area say me that my game have a very high energy impact. Depends on what? How can I improve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your energy usage by looking over your performance use. Are you doing heavy work on every frame `update()` function? Can you optimise your algorithms? Use the `Instruments` app to aid your profiling:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/